# egress policy not getting applied with kubernetes 1.9

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deny all egress traffic . So I created this network policy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

And then i applied it to namespace

kubectl -n pps-api-gateway-ci apply -f ~/Documents/networkpolicy.yaml

to test this , I did describe networkpolicy

```
    kubectl -n pps-api-gateway-ci describe networkpolicy
    Name:         default-deny
    Namespace:    pps-api-gateway-ci
    Created on:   2018-05-29 13:50:52 -0700 PDT
    Labels:       <none>
    Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration= 
   {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"NetworkPolicy","metadata": 
   {"annotations":{},"name":"default-deny","namespace":"pps-api-gateway- 
   ci"},"spec"...
   Spec:
      PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this 
    namespace)
      Allowing ingress traffic:
        <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
       Allowing egress traffic:
        <none> (Selected pods are isolated for egress connectivity)
       Policy Types: Egress
```

then i logged into that container

ping www.google.com

```
PING www.google.com (216.58.217.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=2.552 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=1.835 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=1.487 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=2.523 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=1.607 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.100: icmp_seq=5 ttl=46 time=1.480 ms
```

I should not be able to ping if my egress policy is applied.

I am working with kubernetes 1.9.6 version

Comment: Can you add information about which networking solution you are using and how you installed it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/):

> Network policies are implemented by the network plugin, so you m**ust be using a networking solution** which supports NetworkPolicy - **simply creating** the resource without a controller to implement it will **have no effect**.

A number of networking plugins, including [Calico](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/calico-network-policy/) and [Weave Net](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/weave-network-policy/), support using `Network Policies`, but [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel), for example, doesn’t.

Comment: We already have network plugins which is in kube-system namespace